# Not able to launch 13.10 installer on asus n56j

Tags: installation, asus

After a few seconds of running ubuntu OS installer black screen occurs as shown:

[image]

Comment: Resolved by switching to non-gui installer. After installation ubuntu runs only with kde or xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my Asus N56J. At the point of failure, the system error points to the a problem with nouveau drivers. To get around this, you want to edit the grub menu.

When the grub menu appears, edit the entry that you want to boot by pressing 'e'. Move to then end of the line that begins with 'linux', and add "nomodeset" (no quotes). Press 'F10' to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the BIOS and enable the legacy boot, you are trying to load it via UEFI and it sometimes gives errors.

Then load via non-UEFI the USB and you will be able to install it without problems, please give feedback on the solution and if the problem isn´t solved please give more details and upload a better screen to see what it is displaying, thank you.

PS: press delete or F1 or F2 or F9 or F10 to enter the BIOS, I don´t know which one it is for Asus laptops.